# Estimating abundance using non-normal count data

Tags: bayesian, inference, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I have sample counts of $n=20$ or $n=7$ taken from right-skewed and zero-inflated populations.  The challenge in each case is to use the sample to estimate the total count in that population.  Each of the populations are constituted of 300 such counts.

As the sample mean ($\times 300$) tends to be unrepresentative can anyone advise a more robust analysis?  Some examples of the samples below.  Many thanks.

n=20 samples:

```
a <- c(0,    3,   31,    0,    0,  350,   32,  750,   63,  630,   91,   65,    0,   
      85,    0,  180,   14,  220,   75,  550)

b <- c(96,  210,   50,  195,  500,  450,   45,  180,  150,    0,   22,  250,  900,  
      190,  500,  110,  300,   25,  280,   40)

c <- c(6,    0,    3,    0,    3,   37,   52,   23,    8,    0,   23,    0,    0,    
       0,    3,   16,    6,   23,    1,    2)

d <- c(5400, 1800, 4500,  900, 3500, 3100, 5300, 1300, 4800, 4200, 7000,  777,    0,    
          5,   42,  850,  700,  550,  500,   18)

e <- c(0,    0,  180,  135,  150,   90,    0,   22,   55,    0,  30,    0,  150,   45,   
       0,    8,    0,    0,    0,   40)
```

In addition there was a larger pilot sample of n=76:

```
p <- c(16,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  76,  18,  12,   0, 121,   0,   0,   0,   0,
        0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  30,   0,  
       78,  94,   0,  23,  43,   0,  46,  21, 112,   0,   0,   0,  20,   0,   0, 210,  
      453,  89, 596, 310, 602,  90, 254, 580,   7,   0,  10,   0,  64, 750,  18, 830,  
       45, 360,   0,  80,  52,  60,  93, 270,  35,  20,   0,  20)
```

nb.1.  In case of interest these are counts of a plant species' flowers in $1\,\text{m}^2$-quadrats in stands of vegetation of area $300\,\text{m}^2$.  The stands were sown with the same seed at the same intensity.  Trailing zeroes are where the surveyor scaled up rather than count every individual flower.

nb.2.  My interpretation of these data is that the quadrats are confounding presence/absence with abundance-where-present.  But it seems reasonable to assume that a species has a characteristic probability distribution of abundance-where-present, albeit a J-shaped one.  My half-baked solution is to model that distribution (from the pilot sample) as a negative binomial, then combine it as a conjugate prior with the beta-distributed presence/absence of the 7- or 20- quadrat sample.  If this approach is justified I would very much appreciate some demo R code.

Comment: It would be normal to avoid naming a variable "c" since there's a function by that name already. It's not that you *can't* do it - you can - it's just that it's likely to be less confusing if you avoid using standard function names as variable names, especially given that functions are variables.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b for good points.  I use the word unrepresentative for the mean as its estimate of abundance can be so variable and so far away from the actual abundance, e.g. taking a random subset of those pilot data, (sample mean x 76) tends to not be a reliable estimate of its total.

Comment: How can such a question be answered without a definition of 'reliable'?

Comment: My hope is that we can do better than use the mean model.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.. What do you mean by 'use the sample to estimate the total count in that population'? Are you trying to understand the expected count of a population based on a sample from that same population?

Comment: Hi Matthew sorry if that was not clear.  Yes the aim is to estimate the total population count, i.e. flowers per 300m2, at the site where the quadrats were surveyed.

Comment: [Zero-inflated models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model) might be appropriate, except probably a negative binomial here rather than a Poisson.

Comment: Thanks Matthew and I wonder if anyone could demo this?  I have also just experimented with a zero-truncated negative binomial in {vgam} which I will paste in the next comment.  I suppose the missing step for me then is how to apply a fitted model to the samples a to e.

Comment: density_where_present<-(p[!p==0])
#
library(VGAM)
#
ztnb_model <- vglm(density_where_present ~ 1, family = posnegbinomial())   
#
summary(ztnb_model)
#
hist(density_where_present,breaks=15,prob=T,xlim=c(0,max(density_where_present)))
#
lines(x<-seq(min(density_where_present),max(density_where_present)),dposnegbin(x, size=Coef(ztnb_model)["size"], prob = NULL, munb=Coef(ztnb_model)["munb"]), col="red")

Comment: Apologies the #s in the above R code should represent line breaks; I have now discovered that this is done with <br/> but the 5-minute editing deadline has passed.